# Save image from URL multiple times

Tags: php

I am making a crawler that will put content(images) onto my website, i have made a script that crawls and saves the url to a image fine but now i need to upload the images to my server so that i can use them on my website.

I have seen people saying that file_put_contents should be used but you have to specify the image name and ext but it will be dynamic?

Comment: So you are not running your crawler on the same server your website is on?

Comment: if you're downloading and saving, you should have the name of what you've download, so you can use that to upload.  Alternatively, you could do the upload out of stream and just walk your downloads directory, and upload each file you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [file_get_contents()](http://us.php.net/file_get_contents) and [file_put_contents()](http://us.php.net/file_put_contents)

```
$image = 'http://example.org/image.jpg';
$filename = basename($image);
$content = file_get_contents($image);
file_put_contents('/path/to/your/dir/'.$filename, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` would probably be the most simple method.

To avoid collisions (files with the same name), you can make the url part of the file name:

Assuming an array of URLs:

```
$path = '/path/to/image/folder/';
$urls = array(
    'http://www.somesite.no/some_image.jpg',
    'http://www.someothersite.no/some_other_image.jpg',
    'http://www.someothersite.no/another_image.jpg'
);
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $file_content = file_get_contents($url);
    $filename = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/", "", $url);
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "-", $filename);
    file_put_contents($path.$filename, $file_content);
}
```

**Documentation**

- `file_get_contents` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
- `file_put_contents` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php
- `preg_replace` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- `str_replace` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php